# Adding array result to a string

Tags: javascript, html, math, random, background

This is a little script randomizing what picture should it display. I can easily set this to an `<img>` using `document.getElementById("pic").src = randPics[randNumGen]`, but the `background` tag requires me to use `url()`. How can I set `document.body.style.background` to "url(and the random image here)"? Please no JS libraries.

```js
const randPics = ["https://i.ibb.co/6JBbMYm/pic1.jpg", "https://i.ibb.co/rHjTdfc/pic2.jpg"];

window.onload = choosePicture();

function choosePicture() {
  let randNumGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * randPics.length);
  console.log(randNumGen);
  document.body.style.background = "randPics[randNumGen]";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script async src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img width="500px" src="#" alt="pic" id="pic">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `window.onload = choosePicture();` you are immediately calling the function, and assigning the (`undefined`) return. That's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: @ASDFGerte What else should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = randPics[randNumGen];

document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ url + "')";
```